# Org timestamp prompt that returns timestamp as a string?

Tags: org-mode, time-date

The function `#'org-time-stamp` prompts a minibuffer that reads control strings from the user, and call `#'org-insert-time-stamp` to insert the resulting time stamp as a string into the buffer. For example, the control string `"2021-01-01 9am"` results to the time stamp `"<2021-01-01 Fri 09:00>"`.

How to factor these functions to create a new function that still prompts a minibuffer, but only returns a string without insertion? Some thing like

```
(org-time-stamp-read "2021-01-01 9am") 
;; => "<2021-01-01 Fri 09:00>"
```

Answer (score 2):

`org-read-date` does what you want:

```
org-read-date is a compiled Lisp function in `org.el'.

(org-read-date &optional WITH-TIME TO-TIME FROM-STRING PROMPT
DEFAULT-TIME DEFAULT-INPUT INACTIVE)

Read a date, possibly a time, and make things smooth for the user.
```

Answer (score 0):

A direct way that offers the same result is

```
(with-temp-buffer
  (org-time-stamp nil)
  (buffer-string))
```

However, this is not efficient enough. I still hope to see a proper factoring.

Comment: Why do you think that is not efficient enough?

Comment: Because `#'org-time-stamp` must have included the functionality I want. My method effectively gets the desired string, write it to a temporary buffer, and then copy the buffer string to the result.

Comment: You are right that it is (slightly) inefficient in that respect, but in practice, this is a pretty good way to go: the inefficiency is probably not going to manifest itself unless you do this millions of times. You  can try profiling the code and see how much of a difference it makes. I grant you that the other answer is probably a better way to go in this case.